# Input type number field with decimal values displays a comma instead of a period

Tags: php, html, input, woocommerce, product-quantity

I'm using Woocommerce for a project and I want people to be able to order products with a decimal value.

Now I fixed this problem pretty easily with this code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_quantity_input_min', 'min_decimal');
function min_decimal($val) {
  return 0.5;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_quantity_input_step', 'nsk_allow_decimal');
function nsk_allow_decimal($val) {
  return 0.5;
}

remove_filter('woocommerce_stock_amount', 'intval');
add_filter('woocommerce_stock_amount', 'floatval');
```

However for some reason the HTML on the site outputs the values with commas instead of periods like so:

```
<input id="quantity_5a66016934e7b" class="input-text qty text" step="0,5" min="0,5" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Aantal" size="4" pattern="" inputmode="" type="number">
```

Which obviously doesn't work since it's using commas instead of periods. However I have no idea what's causing this. I've already set my global divider in woocommerce to a period thinking that'd be the problem but it's not.

Any idea what could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your code and it's working fine even if the field displays a coma instead of a period.
When looking at the source code **the value in the field is set with a period**, but the displays shows that with a coma.

Below you can click on **"Run code snippet"** button and you will see:

```html
<div class="quantity">
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_5a660e741bc2f">Quantity</label>
    <input type="number" id="quantity_5a660e741bc2f" class="input-text qty text" step="0.5" min="0.5" max="506" name="quantity" value="0.5" title="Qty" size="4" pattern="[0-9.]*" inputmode="numeric">
</div>
```

> So as you can see, **the field value** is **`0.5`**, **but the display** is **`0,5`**… 
> Is just the **normal behavior** for this html5 `<input type="number">` field and so this has nothing to do with WooCommerce.

In [this related documentation about `<input type="number">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) "**Allowing decimal values**" section, the same thing happens. The value in the source is with a period, but displayed with a coma

In woocommerce you can control also everything in **`woocommerce_quantity_input_args`** unique filter hook:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'custom_quantity_input_args', 20, 2 );
function custom_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
    $args['input_value'] = 0.5; // Default starting value (Optional)
    $args['min_value'] = 0.5;
    $args['step'] = 0.5;
    $args['pattern'] = '[0-9.]*';
    $args['inputmode'] = 'numeric';

    return $args;
}
```

And you should need also (as in your code) this:

```
remove_filter('woocommerce_stock_amount', 'intval');
add_filter('woocommerce_stock_amount', 'floatval');
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: My problem was actually that the site generated code had put commas in the values of the number input instead of periods, thus making them not work since you can't do that. However your code looks a lot nicer than what I had going and made me find what the problem actually was. For those of you who want to know in a file my locale was set to NL which for some reason changed it to a comma. Which makes no sense to me but oh well it's fixed, thanks for the reply! (also if you set the input value this will set the input value of everything in the cart to that too, so be mindful of that)